# vectorize numpy append loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize the following loop in I am trying to append multiple arrays to an empty array.

```
# ff is a matrix of shape [100,1,96]
temp = np.array([]).reshape(0,96)
for kk in range(1,10,1):
   temp = np.append(tr,ff[kk],axis=0)
temp = temp.reshape(1,10,96)
```

Is it possible to vectorize the above loop using numpy? Any help is welcome!

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to loop over elements of a matrix of dimension [100,1,96] which are of dimension [1,96] and appending to them to create [10,96] array

Comment: So the first 10 entries of the first dimension and all entries of all other dimensions? Shouldn't `ff[:10,:,:]` just give you the data you are looking for?

Comment: yes, that works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding array append v. list append: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41793600/901925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing to extract the data you need:

```
ff[:10,:,:]
```

That will yield an array of shape `(10, 1, 96)`. To get rid of the empty dimension, you can run it through `numpy.squeeze()`:

```
numpy.squeeze(ff[:10,:,:])
```

and get an array of shape `(10, 96)`